# PHP json decode data using foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have this following link and i want to print every item with id using foreach from json decoded string. Do you know how can i get these items using foreach?
[sample JSON data](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/profileicon.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/profileicon.json");

$data = json_decode($json_data, true);

$items = $data['data'];

foreach($items as $item){
    // Here you can get $item['id'] and $item['image'] and echo or do what you want with that data
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) dedicated for this, that creates object with data? You can then iterate over this object.

Answer (score 0):

Load data via **cURL**:

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_data, 1);
foreach($data as $item) 
{
    var_dump($item);
    //...
}
```